# WinRT: What happens when file is shared via file extension?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, communication

I'm recently looking into the file-sharing features of Windows Phone 8.1. One possibility is, to do this via file extensions. My question is, how exactly my app gets access to a launched file that it registered to handle.

I know that in WP8 this was done with a URI and a file token (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but since the SharedStorageAccessManager class is not available anymore, I guess that it must be done different in 8.1.

So: What happens on "OS-level" in Win8.1/WP8.1 when an app is launched via a file extension, and how does the target-app actually get the launched file?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

The app can register as a file handler in its Package.appxmanifest. Openthe manifest designer in Visual Studio, go to the Declarations tab, and add a File Type Associations declaration. You'll be prompted to fill out the details.

The app's [Application.OnFileActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated.aspx) method will be called with the launched StorageFiles in the [FileActivatedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs.aspx).[Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs.files.aspx) property.

See [How to handle file activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779669.aspx) and the [Association Launching sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=231484) for documentation and walkthroughs.

At a system level this all gets stored in the registry and when the launcher is called on a file the shell looks up the association then uses COM (or historically command line parameters or DDE) to launch or connect to the app registered for the file type. The details are hidden from Windows Runtime apps but are more directly exposed to desktop apps on Windows. See File [type and URI associations model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047.aspx) [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521657(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was more like: What happens _really_ on system level? How does the OS know, that my process is allowed to get access to the launched file?

Comment: The app registers for the file as shown in the linked docs. I've edited in a summary.